# What does the Lost Word attack from the Knocker demon do in Shin Megami Tensei: Devil Summoner: Soul Hackers?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, soul-hackers

I recruited [this demon](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/devil-summoner-soul-hackers/Knocker) very early in the game. It had an attack called Lost Word that I used once and automatically killed all the other demons in my party. I was wondering, is this really its only use? It didn't even do any damage to the other enemies I was facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Megami Tensei Wiki, the ["Lost Word" magic skill](http://megamitensei.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Devil_Summoner:_Soul_Hackers_skills#Almighty_.28magic.29) can be used by Garuda, Huangdi, and Nemechi Knocker.

It will randomly do one of 4 effects:

- Turns all allied demons Undead
- Deal Almighty damage to all enemies
- Flee from battle
- deal to Caster Almighty damage

Comment: I think the "Turns all allied demons Undead" might be a mistranslation implying "kills all allied demons in your party", because that's exactly what happened.